# Assign Multiple value in one variable wtih react native on Stack.screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
<Stack.Screen 
      key={route.name}
      name={route.name}
      component={route.component} // Home, Pertes
      // if header is true then option returned is {header:  null}
       
      options ={route.label !== '' ? {title: route.label}  : {header: noop}  }   
    />
```

i try to assign this code **Style** to options :

```
{headerTitleStyle: {fontFamily: 'arial', fontSize: 20,},
      headerStyle: { marginTop: 24, },}
```

the result that i wanna get is the variable options  = the Condition  + the code **style**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it this way:

1. Create a constant with the style

```
const myHeaderStyle= {
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'arial', 
        fontSize: 20
    },
    headerStyle: { 
        marginTop: 24
    }
};
```

2. Concatenate the style with the rest of the options

```
<Stack.Screen 
      key={route.name}
      name={route.name}
      component={route.component}
      options ={route.label !== '' ? {...myHeaderStyle, title: route.label}  : {...myHeaderStyle, header: noop}  }   
/>
```

Or more elegant

```
const options= {
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'arial', 
        fontSize: 20
    },
    headerStyle: { 
        marginTop: 24
    }
};

if (route.label !== '') {
    options.title = route.label;
} else {
    options.header = noop;
}
```

And

```
<Stack.Screen 
      key={route.name}
      name={route.name}
      component={route.component}
      options ={options}   
/>
```